# I am on itch.io and i found this game that looks cool but it is a zip file. and im unsure if it is safe

Tags: windows-10

All of my time on windows I have never seen a .zip file as an "application." is it safe or should I avoid it. Can someone respond asap? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly common for small games and applications to be distributed this way rather than as an installer like some larger software packages.

itch.io is a very above-board platform for developers, I've never heard of anyone using it to try and distribute malware, at least not successfully.

You should be fine